# Error: Cannot find module 'semver' when calling jhipster -version

Tags: npm, jhipster, semantic-versioning

When I tried to run JHipster by `jhipster --version` I have the following error.  I know its related to node js but I cannot solve it. Your advice please.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/jhipster:20:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
```

Comment: It apparently can't find the semver module. Either your JHipster or node js installation is broken, or the environment you are running it from is broken. What have you tried by way of eliminating some of those? Have you read the user docs for any of those products? Log files perhaps? Maybe a debugger to see exactly where it's looking for the semver module and checking that against where is should looking? Do you even have NPM installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jwdonahue said something is broken so possible workaround would be to delete node_modules and reinstall again.

Just remove `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\` then now install again node and now test. It will work.

I had the same error. `npm uninstall npm -g`, `rm -rf node_modules` didn't help me, because when I tried I was getting `Error: Cannot find module 'semver'`. But I solve my problem with these steps (this will delete other global modules you may be using):

- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm`
- `brew uninstall --force node`
- `brew install node`

Hope this will help those who are getting a similar problem.